# Como manter o áudio de uma cena para outra no unity

Tags: unity3d, áudio

Estou começando no unity e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com o áudio de uma cena seja reproduzido em outra, sendo que esse áudio será reproduzido, na outra cena, começando do instante em que parou na cena anterior.
Se souberem peço que respondam bem explicado, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Só criar um `gameObject`, colocar pra tocar o áudio nele e criar um script com:

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: "cria um script..." cria o script onde? "só criar um gameObject.." qualquer um? Ou pode ser um `empty`? Sua resposta pode ser melhor. Por favor, edite-a para adicionar os detalhes. Se possível, adicione pequenas imagens com as partes essenciais da tela onde isso é feito, pra que ela seja realmente útil ao AP (Autor da Pergunta) e a outros futuros leitores. Se fizer, ganha meu +1.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, crie um script, no meu exemplo SoundController.

Dentro do script criado coloque o código

```
public class soundController : MonoBehaviour {


void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Após isso arraste o script para o seu object sound. Funcionará perfeitamente.